# Aerospike missing data when adding new node to cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, aerospike

I have a Aerospike (3.11.1.1) cluster with 6 nodes. When I try to add a new node, sometimes some objects are "temporarily" lost while the cluster is migrating data. After the migration finishes, the missing data return. Is this a BUG or am I doing something wrong? How to avoid

Notices that while migration happens, the master object count is lower then the actual final object count after migration finishes

Master and replica count **before** finishing migrations:

[image: Master and replica count before finishing migrations]

Master and replica count **after** finishing migrations:

[image: Master and replica count after finishing migrations]

My aerospike.conf:

```
service {
    user root
    group root
    paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
        paxos-recovery-policy auto-reset-master
    pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
    service-threads 32
    transaction-queues 32
    transaction-threads-per-queue 4
        batch-index-threads 40
    proto-fd-max 15000
        batch-max-requests 30000
        replication-fire-and-forget true
}

logging {
    # Log file must be an absolute path.
    file /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log {
        context any info
    }
}

network {
    service {
        #address any
        port 3000
    }

    heartbeat {
                mode mesh
                mesh-seed-address-port 10.240.0.32 3002
                mesh-seed-address-port 10.240.0.33 3002
                port 3002

        interval 150
        timeout 20
    }

    fabric {
        port 3001
    }

    info {
        port 3003
    }
}

namespace mynamespace {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 1500M
    default-ttl 0 # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.
        ldt-enabled true
        write-commit-level-override master

    storage-engine device {
          file /data/aerospike.dat
          #device /dev/sdb
          write-block-size 1M
          filesize 280G
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the discrepancy was due to an issue in the original migration/rebalance design and is addressed in the protocol change in [Aerospike 3.13](https://aerospike.com/docs/operations/upgrade/cluster_to_3_13/index.html). Prior to the protocol change in 3.13, when running `replication-factor` 2, the operator must upgrade one node at a time and wait for migrations to complete afterwards.

Additional discrepancy is Aerospike avoiding over counting `master-objects` and replica objects (i.e. `prole-objects`) during migration. Also with 3.13 we added a stat for the [`non-replica-objects`](https://aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/index.html#non_replica_objects) which are objects that are not currently acting as master or replica. These are either (a) objects on a partition that has inbound migrations and will eventually act as replica  or (b) these are objects on a partition that will not participate and will be dropped when migrations terminate for the partition.

Prior to 3.13, `non-replica-object` of type (a) would reduce the counts for both `master-objects` or `prole-objects`. This is because prior to the protocol change, when a partition returns that was previously master, it immediately resumes as master even though it doesn't have the new writes that took place while it was away. This isn't optimal behavior but it isn't losing data since we will resolve the missing records from the `non-replica-objects` on other nodes. Post protocol change, a returning 'master' partition will not resume as 'master' until it has received all migrations from other nodes.

Prior to 3.13, `non-replica-objects` of type (b) would immediately drop and would reduce the count for `prole-objects`. This causes the `replication-factor` of records written while a node was away to be reduced by one (e.g. `replication-factor 2` temporarily becomes `replication-factor 1`). This is also the reason it was important to wait for migrations to complete before proceeding to upgrade the next node. Post protocol change (unless running in-memory only), it is no longer necessary to wait for migrations to complete between node upgrades because the interim 'subset partitions' aren't dropped which prevents record's `replication-factor` from being reduced (actually, with the new protocol, during migrations there are often `replication-factor` + 1 copies of a record).

Comment: I would migrate to 3.13, but I can't because when I start a new empty node on 3.13, some objects are missing because of this BUG. The best solution maybe would be to backup the current cluster, create a completely new cluster in new version and restore the backup there

Comment: That isn't accurate. Prior to 3.13, restarting a single node reduces the effective `replication-factor` of some of the records by 1, these are only the records which are written while the node was away. By waiting for migration to complete after restarting the node, these records will replicate to their configured `replication-factor`. Even while not fully replicated, your application will still be able to find the records via 'duplicate resolution'. (minor correction to previous comment which I will  now delete)

Comment: Also, since you are replacing nodes with empty nodes, all records will effectively have their `replication-factor` reduced by 1 (since you are essentially deleting one of the copies). Additionally, since empty nodes do not participate as master while they have pending inbound migrations, you will have the optimal node (the node with the full set of data) acting as master. Finally, since the upgraded nodes are empty, duplicate resolution wouldn't be required.